# Get all active HttpSession in RESTEasy implementaion

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I need to get list of all the active Session so that I can manage them. Basically I need to manage all the logged in Users in application. 
Using HttpServletRequest req I am able to get current session but 
need to get all the sessions

Something like this:

```
     public EmployeeTO getEmployeeById(int id, HttpServletRequest req) {
        EmployeeTO employeeTO = null;
        try{

            HttpSession session = req.getSession();
            HttpSessionContext httpSessionContext = session.getSessionContext();


        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return employeeTO;
    }
```

Am using RESTFul implementation with JASS for Login

Answer (score 1):

> I have a screen which shows the list of all active Users. If I check one
>   User and click close session. I need to terminate that users session.
>   To do that I need to have sessions somewhere accessible.

Using the `HttpServletRequest`, you will be able to get only the current request's (user's) `session` object. But if you want to track all `session` objects, you can do that by implementing `HttpSessionListener` as shown below:

```
  public class MyProjectSessionListenerAndInvalidator 
                                 implements HttpSessionListener {

     private static Map<String,Session> sessions = new HashMap<>();

      @Override
      public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
          //add your code here, 
          //this will be invoked whenever there is a new session object created
           //Get the newly created session
           Session session = event.getSession();
           //get userId or unique field from session
           sessions.put(userId, session);
      }

      @Override
      public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
         //add your code here
         //this will be invoked whenever there is a new session object removed

          //Get the removed session
          Session session = event.getSession();
          //get userId or unique field from session
          sessions.remove(userId);
      }

      public R getSessions() {
         //add code here
      }

      public void invalidateSession(String userId) {
         //add code here
      }
 }
```

**N.B.:** I recommend to use `getSessions()` and `invalidateSession()` **carefully**.

Comment: Thing is I have a screen which shows list of all active Users. If I check one User and click close session. I need to terminate that users session. To do that I need to have sessions somewhere accessable